# How do I completely clean-up or reset a Python installation on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, apt

Package management and juggling pip, anaconda, PPAs, and virtual-environments is difficult. Somewhere in my constellation of dependencies, things are broken. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. As far as I know, I cannot fix these dependencies by hand.

The problem, for what it's worth: I've been unable to use tensorflow for a few months. Every time I try to fix it, even uninstalling and reinstalling everything to the best of my knowledge, things still don't work. After sinking enough hours, I'm looking for a "nuclear solution".

What I would like to do is cleanly remove everything except Python and any Python packages my system might require, so that I can start fresh (and hopefully do things *properly*.)

So, my question: **How can I systematically clean up or remove my Python installation?** I want to wipe everything and start anew. Does there exist a systematic guide, or a smart and reputable script that does this?

Comment: What is the error from tensorflow? Perhaps the nuclear solution is a little hasty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Helpful and cautionary tale, be a good idea not to delete it I think... I'll assume it was the profanity that got it deleted so I've edited it out.

!!!! WARNING !!!!

If you're like me and you think ah shur I'll do an 'apt list --installed | grep -i python' and then 'apt purge -y' all that crap, well, maybe don't.

Now my entire system is doo-doo. It all seemed fine until I rebooted and now there is no network connection, netplan and a bunch of other stuff is just gone. No recovery possible.

Actually it looks like it was an 'apt autoremove' AFTER I'd done the above that actually removed netplan.

And all because I wanted to remove multiple python versions to get over those gosh darn import issues and messin' around with pip and pip3 and pip3432432 and what gosh flippin' version of python is tied to what oody doody version of pip...

UPDATE - This video helped me recover me files https://youtu.be/tGIPeWkPkMc

Comment: Ohh man, this gave me a good laugh. Mostly because you called your system "doo-doo". I'm 32, what is wrong with me, I can't stop rotfl.

Comment: Genuinely glad you got a laugh out of it @Bryant

Comment: Glad you got it back.  Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

(Extending @jay 's warning)

"Out of the Box", later Ubuntu versions have a system dependency on Python(3).  For instance, my Ubuntu 20.04 runs "networkd-dispather" and "unattended-upgrade-shutdown".  I've seen similar on various Cloud instances.  Kali 2020 uses python to run a printer daemon.  Check your system first.  Or even try it on a VM similar to your system.

Try a quick check before doing something drastic.

```
ps aux | grep python
```

That will give you an idea if services are being run by Python.  Frankly, I like the `pip3 freeze` to list the installed packages and cleanup from that list, like @sortas suggests in the second half of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo apt purge python-pip python-dev`, or `python3` and `python3-pip` if you're using Python 3. This must remove all files/folders created by the installed packages. But I'm not really sure you need to do it.

The better solution is just to uninstall all pip packages, like `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y`. Just to be sure you can even remove pip folder `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` manually (or similar folder for Python 3).

Comment: Sorry for getting back to this so late -- this worked! I had to run it a few times (it didn't work for certain folders).

I'm using Conda environments responsibly now and everything seems to be working properly. :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: **DO NOT PURGE YOUR PYTHON FILES** This will wreck your system. I just tested it out on a VM and there is **no safe way to purge your python installation**.

Comment: Giving me `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/__pycache__/appdirs.cpython-38.pyc'` even with `sudo`